# ¿Como hago para que una imagen que tengo de fondo en react no se aplique a todas las paginas?

Tags: css

Soy bastante nuevo en este mundillo y mi problema es ese, tengo homePage.js y le aplique un css con una foto de fondo, me voy a settings.js y la dichosa foto esta de fondo.

Estoy usando:

```
* {
 background: url(la fotillo de marras) no-repeat center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Creo que el fallo esta en el "*" pero si uso className= por el motivo que sea no funciona.

Comment: Pues accediendo únicamente a la clase que le pongas a tu imagen...

Comment: y como hago eso exactamente? la imagen es una imagen separada que esta en la carpeta public (estoy trabajando con la aplicacion de npx create-react-app)

Comment: Estas utilizando * {} para generar una regla CSS, el * aplica a todos los elementos

Comment: Lectura recomendada -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors, saludos.

Comment: @Arty como te dijeron, el problema es el selector (en css el selector es lo que esta antes de ``{}``). En este caso estas usando un comodin, ``*`` que quiere decir que todos los elementos de tu sitio van a usar esas reglas CSS. En pocas palabras le estas poniendo ese fondo a todo. Suponiendo que en tu homePage.js tenes un div con un ``className="soy-un-div"``, si vos le queres aplicar el fondo a esa clase, tenes que hacer, en tu codigo CSS, ``.soy-un-div {background...}``. Vas a tener que leer los fundamentos de CSS para entender los selectores.